# Can't write on FAT32 partition although having rw mount option?

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, fat32

I have recently moved from Ubuntu 16 to 18 and I have a problem using a partition that I have set it automatically mount on startup. The problem is shift-delete or right click-new folder are not working. In terminal I have to do it by `sudo`. I added an `fstab` option `rw` to make it writable but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `man mount`, especially the "`Mount options for fat`" part. You can use the `uid=` and `gid=` options to make all the files owned by the specified UID and GID. If it's already mounted, you could do something like

```
target=/dev/...
mntdir=the directory where it should be mounted
sudo mount -t vfat -o remount,rw,user,users,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2 $target $mntdir
```

Comment: I changed both `uid` and `gid` to 1000 (my user id) and now it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**GUI Method For Write Permission to Fat32 Partition**

Use the gnome-disks or Disks application of your ubuntu. The Disks program will automatically edit /etc/fstab.
Select the fat32 partition that needs to be mounted and then select *'Additional Partition Options'* (cogs) icon, to access the **'Edit Mount Options'**.

In **'Mount Options'**, deselect *'User Session Defaults'*. If you want to auto-mount the partition then select *'Mount at System startup'*. Also add comma separated dmask=000 and fmask=111 ([Mount Options Image for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUKar.png)) to the input box above *'Mount Point'*, to get the **write** access to the partition. Save the settings.