# Command Line "Mount" Equivalent to GUI

Tags: command-line, 20.04, mount, xubuntu

I have a separate FAT32 partition that resides on a Xubuntu 20.04 persistent USB live drive.

When I boot up, that drive is not mounted. If I double click on the unmounted drive, it mounts and I can write to it just fine.  However, I want to be able to mount this in a writable mode via command line and not involve double-clicking in the GUI. If instead I try to create a mount point and then mount the drive via command line, it will only mount in read-only.

Here are a couple of things that I have tried:

```
sudo mkdir /media/xubuntu/foo
```

Then I try to mount the drive to that mountpoint:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/xubuntu/foo
```

It results in read only.

When running:

```
sudo mount -o rw /dev/sda3 /media/xubuntu/foo
```

also results in read only.

What else can I try?

Comment: Which version of Xubuntu are you using?

Comment: Is it *really* read-only - or does your non-root user simply not have permission to write to it?

Comment: Indeed, by default, the drive mouned this way will be readable by root only. Change ownership or permissions of mount point.

Comment: @user68186 - I edited my post to show 20.04

Comment: @steeldriver - I have no idea. How do I check?

Comment: @vanadium - Yes, I see in the permissions tab that root is read/write but all others is read-only. However, all the selection pull down boxes are greyed out. How can I change ownership or permissions of the mount point?

Comment: Since this is a persistent live USB (not a full install) I am not sure if it will work: Try opening the `disks` utility navigate to (select) this FAT32 partition. Then mark the box, for **automatically mount this partition** (or some such thing). Then restart to see if it makes any difference after the reboot.

Comment: @user68186 that will not solve the permission issue. Change permissions using `sudo chmod`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't write on FAT32 partition although having rw mount option?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113469/cant-write-on-fat32-partition-although-having-rw-mount-option)

Answer (score 3):

when you click in gui it is not mount command that is working under the hood, it is udisks2.

```
udisksctl mount -b blockdevice name (example /dev/sdb1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In linux, a drive is by default mounted with `root` as owner. For a `vfat` file system, you can only change ownership/permissions for the whole volume at once, because `vfat` does not support unix file permissions. Thus, to allow reading/writing to the `vfat` partition as user, change the owner of the mount point to the user. That can be done with the command

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/xubuntu/foo
```

where you can literally leave `$USER` if you are the target user. Otherwise, replace `$USER` by the login of the user that needs to have ownership.

Comment: That would be `sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/xubuntu/foo` (notice the colon).

Comment: This command works before the `fat` partition is mounted. However, that does not solve the problem as the partition is still mounted as `root`. Using this command after mounting the partition results in the following error: `chown: changing ownership of '/media/xubuntu/foo': Operation not permitted`.

Comment: @HuHa Thanks for fixing the type.

Comment: @user68186 I cannot test right now, but the permissions of the mount point should propagate to the mounted volume, the entire volume if the mounted file system does not support linux permissions. Explicitly setting permissions in the mount options, as HuHa indicated in his answer, is another possibility, but current approach should also do it. Perhaps try rebooting (I know, this sounds like a curse :-).

Comment: @vanadium I was testing with a normal USB plugged in to an internal Ubuntu installation. I unmounted the USB (using `disks`) as it auto-mounts as I plug it in. The rest of the tests were from the terminal, starting with creating the folder tree: `sudo mkdir -p /media/xubuntu/foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Since that FAT filesystem doesn't have any concept of Linux users and groups, all files are owned by root; unless you tell the `mount` command otherwise with options like `uid=` and/or `gid=`. Your user ID is probably 1000 (the default for the first user account on Ubuntu), likewise for the one user group specifically created for your user account (see `/etc/group`). Use the `id` command to find out.

```
sudo mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda3 /media/xubuntu/foo
```

and you will find that YOU now own the files on that partition, not *root*.

To make those changes permanent, add an entry to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda3  /media/xubuntu/foo  vfat  uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
```

To mount it as yourself without password and no automatically mount it at boot time, use

```
/dev/sda3  /media/xubuntu/foo  vfat  uid=1000,gid=1000,user,noauto  0  0
```

(Notice that the `user` mount option is about permissions to mount and unmount, not who owns the files on the device)

*In an earlier version of this I had recommended to use the `$UID` and `$GID` environment variables, but it turned out that at least `$GID` is not reliably available in all shell environments.*

Comment: Since the system in question is a persistent live USB, editing the `/etc/fstab` may not be possible.

Comment: Well, okay. But the OP might decide to install Ubuntu permanently, and then it makes sense; also for others reading this question who have a similar problem.

Comment: Looks like $GID is not set in all shell environments. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @huha - correct on fstab, I cannot edit it on my persistent live USB. Also, the way this config is to work in this particular, I will not be installing Xubuntu permanently. It will always be used as persistent live USB.